# Py telnetlib OKI with 2.7 but error under 3.6

Tags: python, anaconda, telnetlib

My case is similar to connect Google.com by python 'telnetlib'

With python Anaconda 2.7.10 shell I have the blow script that works well:

```
HOST ="www.google.com"
tn=telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,"80")
tn.write("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+HOST+"\n\n")
l=tn.read_all()
print(l)
```

which gives back:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Location: http://www.google.it/index.html?
gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=A7KiWv_2G6fCXojstrAO
Content-Length: 276
Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2018 16:10:43 GMTenter code here
```

If I now move to Python Anaconda 3.6.3 the same script as above I have the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-4-0f3256299055>", line 3, in <module>
tn.write("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+HOST+"\n\n")

File "C:\Users\FP\Anaconda3\lib\telnetlib.py", line 287, in write
if IAC in buffer:

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytesenter    code here
```

Do you have a suggestions for this ? I red some documentation about the telnetlib but so far did not yet come to a solution :-(. Any idea about what I might try to do ?

Thank you so much ! Fabio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, ultimately, comes down to the difference in how strings are defined in Python 2 and Python 3. If you have never read about this you can look up some material online, for example [this](http://learning-python.com/strings30.html). [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) works with `bytes` objects (Telnet generally works with 7-bit ASCII characters), strings (`str` objects) in Python 3 are text representation without an specific encoding (until you call their [`.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method to convert them to `bytes`). When you call the [`.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.write) method with a regular string, it checks wether it contains `telnetlib.IAC`, which is the bytes object `b'\xff'` (255); since the two objects (the argument and `telnetlib.IAC`) have different types, it fails.

The fix, obviously, is to use only `bytes` objects all along (like strings, but prefixed with `b`):

```
HOST = b"www.google.com"
tn=telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 80)
tn.write(b"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+HOST+b"\n\n")
l=tn.read_all()
print(l)
```

The good thing is, you can also use `b`-prefixed strings in Python 2 (from Python 2.6), they'll just be regular Python 2 strings, so the code works for both versions. You can also look into tools like [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) to make code porting to Python 3 easier (more on the topic [here](http://python3porting.com/)).

Comment: This worked great! I did not realized that so much changed about strings between py 2 and 3. I'll have some more time on the link you mailed. I did not also know about the 2to3  lib, I'll try to convert some code I wrote tiome ago for SAP data analysis. Very interereting you mentioned that jdehesa :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing telnet will want to work in bytes and not the unicode you have.

Maybe try to encode?

`tn.write(("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+HOST+"\n\n").encode('ascii'))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, it worked well :-) !